# Replacing PDF files in Sharepoint with Python without erasing the version history

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, sharepoint

I need to update/replace PDF files on Sharepoint with Python, without erasing the version history.

Using a simple

```
shutil.copyfile(newVersion, currentSharepointversion)
```

works but deletes the version history.

Methods for replacing PDF content don't apply here I guess, since I have tables and images in the PDF, not just text.
Is this possible at all (and how)? I use Python 3.9.

Comment: I'm talking about the Sharepoint document's version history as per [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-the-version-history-of-an-item-or-file-in-a-list-or-library-53262060-5092-424d-a50b-c798b0ec32b1). If you manually replace a document in Sharepoint, the previous version is maintained in the version history, that's what I want to achieve with Python